# Testing with matHorizontalStepper. Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing a test for a mat-stepper.  I am running into the error: Error: Export of name 'matHorizontalStepper' not found!

Thanks to the commnents below I figured it out.

When testing with Angular Material components, you must import them in your test file along with BrowserAnimationsModule and sometimes ReactiveFormsModule.

```
  describe('EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent', () => {
let component: EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent>;
beforeEach(() => {
const activatedRouteStub = () => ({
  snapshot: { paramMap: { get: () => ({}) } }
});



const routerStub = () => ({ navigateByUrl: string => ({}) });
const notificationsServiceStub = () => ({});
const fulfillmentServiceStub = () => ({
  getFulfillmentWorkflows: any => ({ subscribe: f => f }),
  getOrchestratorActionInfo: any => ({ subscribe: f => f }),
  checkIfWorkflowNameExists: any => ({ subscribe: f => f(Boolean) }),
  updateFulfillmentWorkflow: submitFulfillmentWorkflow => ({
    subscribe: f => f({})
  })
});
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent],
  imports: [MatStepperModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useFactory: activatedRouteStub },
    { provide: Router, useFactory: routerStub },
    { provide: NotificationsService, useFactory: notificationsServiceStub },
    { provide: FulfillmentService, useFactory: fulfillmentServiceStub }
  ]
});
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
});


beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
});
it('should create', () => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
```

`});`
   [Edit] the first comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to import all the modules that your component uses.

Because of that, you need to import:

`import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';`

And add it in the `imports` in the of the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})`

Also, if you use a component in your component you need to add in the `declarations: [EditFulfillmentWorkflowComponent],` of the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})`